# Remove space between navbar and header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a weird margin below bootstrap navbar and I don't know how to remove it. Any solutions with manipulate with margin or padding doesn't working.

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Active example <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Example 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Example 2</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<!-- HEADER -->
    <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: -20px; margin-bottom: 25px;">
        <div class="row">
            <img src="http://thehrblog.ecornell.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2013/04/communication.png" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    background-color: #007DBE;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Example is here: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s9kg31et/2/) (please resize 'Result' if menu in navbar is hidden).

I need to remove this space:

[image]

for get this:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file `navbar.less` is adding a `border` on the navbar:

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
    top: 0;
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
}
```

So you can use this to reset:

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
    border:0;
}
```

#### [UpdatedFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s9kg31et/8/)

Comment: if i add this class `.navbar {
border: 0px solid transparent;
}` its also working is this method right

Comment: @sanojlawrence yep that works the point is override the style of the file navbar.less ---- since navabar is also a class on the item with ...fixed-top` also can override on some terms of cascade.

Comment: @Danko: Thanks! Working perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
    top: 0;
}
```

to

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
    border-width: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```